# JQuery Mobile does not update or repost data when navigated away

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have three tabs on the footer: home, promotions and events. I have notification badge implemented such that when a new promotion is loaded in the database, the footer of the mobile page shows 1 and if more are inserted, the number gets incremented in real time. Now, say, if I started with home page, and I see real time notifications on the promotions and events tab. But, when I navigate to the events tab, the notifications go away, but if I click back to the home tab, the notifications show up. I have tried "pageinit" and  "pageshow" separately, with the alert message for test as suggested in other stackoverflow questions. Alert messages show up at each click on the tabs. But, when I tried to modify with the append or html, it does not output me with notification badge. I tried adding id to data-role=page for home, promotions and events, alerts show up, but the append or html functions do not give me results as expected. What I am missing here?

```
    <div data-role="page">

         <div data-role="header">
            ........
         </div>


         <div data-role="content">
                 .......
         </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" >
             <div data-role="navbar" >
                 <ul>
                                   <!---- The notification badge from jquery script get appended in these IDs----->
                                 **<li><div id="home"></div>...........</li>**
                                 **<li><div id="promotion"></div>......</li>**
                                 **<li><div id="event"></div>..........</li>**
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that if my first page is the home page, JQuery Mobile stores it in its history, and any other pages visited will be the ajax calls. And, I have been saving notification badges in the page that they belong to. for eg. if a new promotion is being added, it is being appended to promotion.mobile.erb and if a new event is being added, it is being appended to a div element in event.mobile.erb. I would be able to see it only if my current page is the home page. This was my the issue earlier.

How I resolved it? 
I unDRY'ed my footer and page elements from the application.mobile.erb  and added page ids to home , promotions and events pages. Then, I added different ids to the div elements where the notification badges go.

- for div element in the home_page , I added 0 (you can choose any thing that makes it unique)
- for div element in the promotion_page I added 1  and
- for div element in the event_page I added 2 like in the code below...

  ```
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" >
       <div data-role="navbar" >
           <ul>
                             <!---- The notification badge from jquery script get appended in these IDs----->
                           **<li><div id="home0"></div>...........</li>**
                           **<li><div id="promotion0"></div>......</li>**
                           **<li><div id="event0"></div>..........</li>**
       </div>
  </div>
  ```

Now, when any real time notification comes up, add it to either promotion0 or event0 div so that whenever we navigate away, we can get the old badge from the that div, and repost it to the navigated page div element using pageinit like in the example below...

```
   $('#promo_page').live('pageinit',function(event){
        $('#promotion2').badger(oldBadge0);
        $('#event2').badger(oldBadge_e0);
    });
```